# Is OpenQuery a Good Alternative to RunSQL for Updating SELECT Queries?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently writing an Access macro that will import raw data into tables and perform a sequence of SELECT queries.  I am trying to avoid RunSQL because:

1. SQL codes are too long, cluttering my VBA.
2. I already built the queries in my database, so RunSQL seems redundant.

I tried OpenQuery, which seems to be doing what I want.  Can someone kindly explain the difference between the two methods so I know I can rely on it

Answer (score 0):

If you have built the queries, the simple method is:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim q as DAO.QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb

Set q = db.QueryDefs("SomeQuery")
q.Execute()

Set q = db.QueryDefs("SomeOtherQuery")
q.Execute()

' etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In short using VBA to compose your own query gives you more flexibility than opening a premade query.
Composing the sql string of your query in VBA allows to modify it on the go depending on controls status, variables, etc.

Of course this is not always necessary and it is perfectly fine to use OpenQuery in many cases.

Depending on the task you may also have different performance with the two methods but it largely depends on other elements too.

As for the 'cluttered' SQL code: you can keep that controlled. E.g.

```
strsql = "SELECT idUsr, strLogin, intDep FROM Users WHERE True "

If (condition1) then
    strsql = strsql & " And intDep>30"
else
    strsql = strsql & " And intDep<=30"
end if

'more conditions here
...

'set the order
If (condition9) then
    strsql = strsql & " ORDER BY idUsr, intDep"
Else
    strsql = strsql & " ORDER BY intDep, isUsr"
End If
```